# When should you use a session variable in php?

Tags: php, session-variables, standards

I recently built a security system that controls what pages a user can see and access, I built it so all values for every page in system was stored in a session variable on logging in to avoid having to access the database every page load for the same information.

In a case like this, I feel it is correct to use a session variable. But if it were values used only on a single page, I would access from the database instead.

At what point, between these two extremes, is putting a value in a session variable correct? Or are these more based on what you are storing, like a username, instead of how much you use it?

Comment: Sounds like you'd benefit more from a caching layer. Preloading all pages' data when the user might not access those pages is a waste of resources.

Comment: @ceejayoz I am only storing an array of bit flags to know what links and menu items to display in the header and pages. Nothing about the page content itself, Sorry if i was unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Session variables are stored on your server just like database values are stored on your server.

The difference being instead of querying for individual pieces of information like you can with a database, you are loading the entire "row" (i.e. session) at a time.

There is no reason you couldn't achieve the same performance results by simply storing all of your values inside a single row in your database and querying for that. (Note: doing this with either session variables or database fields are a bad idea) Ultimately, both data sources originate from the server's storage.

That being said...

Session variables traditionally store temporary values related to the state of the client, for example, whether or not the client is logged in at all, when the last login time was, etc.

Database variables should store things you wish to persist beyond that particular client session.

Comment: Wouldn't querying a database for information every page load and then having to parse it ultimately take longer then just querying a session variable for persisting required information like in my example?

Comment: The two are equivalent for equivalent amounts of data. What makes you think retrieving a session variable is faster? It still needs to be read off of server storage somewhere and then submitted in whole to the client to be parsed.